# Fetch polyfill, undefined PromiseValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

Trying to make a `DELETE` request using fetch polyfill, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`, this is the error on `promise.then()`

here is how I do it:

```
function deleteData(item, url) {
  fetch(url + '/' + item, {
    method: 'delete'
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}
```

on the other hand, when I do a `/GET` request, everything works fine:

```
function fetchData(url) {    
  return fetch(url).then(response =>
    response.json().then(json => {
      return json;
    })
  );
}
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right in my answer because you don't tell where you get the error (you *need* that `return` but maybe you get another error before).

Comment: works perfectly. too many hours of coding, need to get some rest, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return the promise:

```
function deleteData(item, url) {
  return fetch(url + '/' + item, {
    method: 'delete'
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}
```